Given the group $G=\{k^a, k^b, k^c, k^d...\}$ under multiplication, is $H=\{a, b, c, d...\}$ under addition guaranteed to also be a group?

Given the group $G=\{k^a, k^b, k^c, k^d...\}$ under multiplication, is H=$\{a, b, c, d...\}$ under addition guaranteed to also be a group?

For context: I have almost zero formal training in math, so apologies if this question seems ridiculous, or is easily provable/disprovable.
My logic for this statement being true is as follows:
Give some value for k, say, e. Additionally, take a group under addition and substitute that for H, say, the group of all integers. Given this example, G and H both being groups holds true and although I have not checked many other examples (in fact, I do not know how to prove other examples as groups in some cases), it seems to hold true.
Is  this even remotely correct, and if so how do you prove it is?

Well your first example doesn’t really make sense since then $G$ is the trivial group and would only have one element so $H$ can’t be the integers.

@Chris wouldn't G in my example be G={$1, e, 1/e, e^2, 1/e^2$...}. Certainly that has more than one element?

"under addition" is unclear. For example, the cyclic group of order $3$ can be written as ${x^1,x^2,x^3}$. Is ${1,2,3}$ "a group under addition"? I would say no. You would need to say "under addition modulo $3$".

@ArturoMagidin the group you mentioned from my understanding, isn't even a group under multiplication, because it doesn't satisfy the closure property. For example, $x^2$ multiplied by $x^3$=$x^5$, which is not part of the set {x^1,x^2,x^3}

In my opinion the answer here is it depends. You seem to assume that $G$ is already known to be a group. If you, more carefully, define $H$ to be the set of all the integers $n$ such that $k^n\in G$, then, indeed, $H$ is a group under addition. The catch is that, with this careful definition in place, if it happens that, say $k^5=k^{15}$ and $k^5$ is in $G$, then both $5$ and $15$ need to be included into  $H$.

In Arturo's example, if $G={x^1,x^2,x^3}$ is a group, then $x^2\cdot x^3=x^5$ must be one of the elements. In other word, either $x^5=x^1$, $x^5=x^2$ or $x^5=x^3$. For example you could have $x=1$, when all three hold. I leave it to you to figure out which of these hold if $x=-1$, or $x=e^{2\pi i/3}$ :-)

I said cyclic group of order 3. That means that $x^a= x^b \iff a\equiv b\pmod{3}$. So $x^5$ is in the set: it happens to be equal to $x^2$ given the operation I explicitly specified. Which is why what you write is unclear. You just don't seem to know what you need to specify in order to describe a group. "under multiplication" and "under addition" doesn't mean anything absent sufficient context, which your question lacks. Your "understanding" is lacking in that you think you are saying something clear, when in fact what you are saying lacks sufficient context.

@ArturoMagidin ah i see, again sorry, I am simply interested in group theory and don't know a whole lot

If your idea is that the symbol $k$ represents some concrete "number" of some kind, perhaps a real number or a complex number, then you might have a good question here, after editing it to express with clarity what $k$ represents. But as you can see, without any specification of what $k$ might represent the question had to be closed.
